# How to export/import breakpoints on VS 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, breakpoints

I'd like to import/export breakpoints which I'm used to export(xml format) from VS 2008/2010, but can't load it from VS2013.

I remember once I upgraded to VS2013 and converted to VS2013 solution from VS2008 environment, breakpoints worked fine. I think I could save one time in VS2013, and tried to load it once I delete them all by accident. Somehow I got the error "Unable to import breakpoints". even I add breakpoints, and tried to export them but got the error "Unable to export breakpoints" on small popup. Would you guide if you have any workaround or solution[image]?

Comment: "Somehow I got the error".  We can't help you if you don't describe *exactly* what you did.  Do you get the error in more than one project?

Comment: Ben Voigt@ I attached the screenshot that I got when trying export breakpoints.

Comment: Both export and import work for me.  Does the problem happen in any other project?

Comment: If you don't care about losing them, I would recommend clicking Delete All Breakpoints, closing the solution and removing the `.suo` file. This usually fixes any issue with breakpoints. Given the nature of your question though I suspect you don't want to lose them.

Comment: Ben Voigt@ I tried to create a new project and have several breakpoints, and export is not still working with the above error message.

Comment: CodeCaster@ Well, that's is not an option for me due to almost 500-600 breakpoints. :-( Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Basically, I wonder where they save breakpoints? Someone says it's in *.suo file and it might be corrupted which *.suo contains breakpoints. why is this related to export/import functionality in VS?

Comment: There's no existing feedback report for this problem at connect.microsoft.com.  Google is also entirely unaware.  So you need to consider an environmental cause, you typically start by disabling addins.  You can file your own feedback report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I reset all settings and it works again as you see at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f407c02b-1afe-45f4-a22b-92cb681b197c/how-to-exportimport-breakpoints-on-vs-2013-while-debugging?forum=vsdebug

Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Well, it didn't work for me. I even made a Repair in Visual Studio and I still can't export breakpoints.

Comment: Worked for me. The issue occurs if you export the breakpoints to XML file, then make some changes to the debugging options (Tools->Options->Debugging), and import the xml file back. If you revert back all the changes you made to the earlier settings, then the breakpoints will be successfully imported!

Answer (score 4):

The answer above worked, but only for a short time, and as soon as I reset all my settings and got the breakpoints set up again, it failed soon after.  The solution was to debug the application and then try saving.  I do have a couple of possible mitigating factors:

1) I'm using Git (and git extensions) as my only add-in
2) I'm building and debugging as Admin in windows 8.1

You might want to try this before you nuke months of useful settings tweaks.

Comment: I too had this problem.  Deleting the suo file didn't help.  But running a debug session and then importing did. Could be related to checking out code.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I was "unable to import breakpoints" on VS2013 just now and then remembered that I changed the startup project yesterday after saving them. When I changed startup back to the original project, the import worked fine. If you're struggling, it may be worth checking any changes at the solution/project level since the export.