# Is it possible to compile VS project in debug version including breakpoints to be debugged via a different project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, pdb-files, physx

I am trying to compile Nvidia PhysX source code in Debug mode. Then I am having another Visual Studio project that uses the PhysX project as an external one.

I want to debug the PhysX project via my main project starting from the breakpoints I am defining in the external PhysX project. Is this possible?

I am using VS 2013 and Physx 3.3.4.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breakpoints are not used by compiler to produce debug information (pdb) or any other binaries. It's an options related to the Visual Studio solution.

Visual Studio stores breakpoints in `"SolutionName".suo` file. This file is also used for other Solution User Options. If your projects are in different solutions it's not possible to automatically use the breakpoints from one in the other.

There is an option to export/import breakpoints between projects. Check ["How to export/import breakpoints on VS 2013?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533189/how-to-export-import-breakpoints-on-vs-2013) article on how to do that.